# IBM Worklight 6.1 [ Received bad token from client]

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

After installing the application from the store, the error below is shown on server logs and I getting an unexpected error from worklight.js as WL.DeviceAuth.saveCertificate failed.

```
DeviceAuthent E com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DeviceAuthenticator checkTokenString FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'fgak243l7r2ulo2k7mnv63ea57', client token:'8396shihvo3h6r3d3h4om53ba8'
```

In  fact, this error is shown only the first time I open the application, then every thing seems Ok. I wonder if the cause is from AppAuthenticity which is disabled from WL console.

I am using Worklight 6.1.0.02.20141216-0421 and  on initOptions.js connectOnStartup is set as true.

Any idea about this issue ?

Comment: You have not mentioned if you are running on Android or iOS. Also, do you always see the message when you launch the application the very first time?

Comment: I am running on Android and the message is shown on every first app launch  after a new install. Also, I noticed that when I clean app data from  my device then I open it again the message appears. Just I want to mention  that in the first view (login) I am invoking an adapter on view init.

Comment: You are running an extremely old build of Worklight 6.1. The latest is IF201611022-042. please upgrade your server, studio and rebuild the application and try again.

Comment: The application  is already on the store, and I must continue with this version in order to avoid a new submission.

Comment: @Idan we have a direct update notification, if the notification is shown the error will not be displayed else if the direct update notification is delayed the error appears the the direct update notification will be shown.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce the error also locally, you should test the new build locally. If it helps, you should make the upgrade in your production system and submit a new version. It could also be that the fix is only on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this issue by changing **connectOnStartup** property to **false**, then I tried to call **WL.Client.connect()** at a later stage in order to connect to the Worklight server.